# Why is CSS positioning not reflected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am following the tut from [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/04/slideout-context-tips-jquery-css3/) but not following the exact codes

My work is http://jsfiddle.net/Zn7br/

I am wondering why my `article.slideLeftBottom` with CSS

```
.js .slideLeftBottom header, .js .slideRightBottom header { // left
    right: 5px;
    left: auto;
}
```

does not have `right` registered ... in FireBug it says `right: 25px`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a `right` property unless your element is positioned absolutely or relatively. Has no effect on `static` elements (static is default)

```
.js .slideLeftBottom header, .js .slideRightBottom header { /* // left <- WRONG */
    position: absolute; /* NEEDED or relative*/
    right: 5px;
    left: auto;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_right.asp

**EDIT**

Took me a bit to notice, but you had added comments to your css with `//`, this doesn't work in CSS (I totally ignored that bit earlier!) and was messing up your code.

I updated your code and it shows properly now : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/Zn7br/2/

Comment: I do have that in `.js .slideOut header` tho?

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of it. All he needs is a pointer on how to use the `right` property. Doesn't even need to go to the link.

Comment: Ok this was totally weird. Your comments were messing things up. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, I always forgot CSS dont use `// comments`